# How do I iterate through the alphabet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, alphabet

1. In Python, could I simply ++ a char?
2. What is an efficient way of doing this?

I want to iterate through URLs and generate them in the following way:

```
www.website.com/term/#
www.website.com/term/a
www.website.com/term/b
www.website.com/term/c
www.website.com/term/d ... 
www.website.com/term/z
```

Comment: There are 308,915,776 (26^6) ways to assemble six letter long strings out of any letters - just so you're aware if you progress beyond doing just one letter.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) which is simply a convenience string of lowercase letters,

Python 2 Example:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

for c in ascii_lowercase:
    # append to your url
```

Python 3 Example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from string import ascii_lowercase as alc
for i in alc:
    print(f"www.website.com/term/{i}")

# Result
# www.website.com/term/a
# www.website.com/term/b
# www.website.com/term/c
# ...
# www.website.com/term/x
# www.website.com/term/y
# www.website.com/term/z
```

Or if you want to keep nesting you can do like so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
for i in alc:
    print(f"www.website.com/term/{i}")
    for j in alc:
        print(f"www.website.com/term/{i}{j}")

# Result
# www.website.com/term/a
# www.website.com/term/aa
# www.website.com/term/ab
# www.website.com/term/ac
# ...
# www.website.com/term/ax
# www.website.com/term/ay
# www.website.com/term/az
# www.website.com/term/b
# www.website.com/term/ba
# www.website.com/term/bb
# www.website.com/term/bc
# ...
# www.website.com/term/bx
# www.website.com/term/by
# www.website.com/term/bz
# www.website.com/term/c
# www.website.com/term/ca
# www.website.com/term/cb
# www.website.com/term/cc
# ...
# ...
# ...
# www.website.com/term/z
# www.website.com/term/za
# www.website.com/term/zb
# www.website.com/term/zc
# www.website.com/term/zd
# ...
# www.website.com/term/zx
# www.website.com/term/zy
# www.website.com/term/zz
```

Comment: For reference `string.ascii_lowercase` provides `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Answer (score 39):

In addition to `string.ascii_lowercase` you should also take a look at the [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) built-ins. `ord('a')` will give you the ascii value for `'a'` and `chr(ord('a'))` will give you back the string `'a'`.

Using these you can increment and decrement through character codes and convert back and forth easily enough. [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) is always a good bookmark to have too.

Comment: Also, if you have `man`, then you can get the ASCII table via `man ascii`.

Comment: Attention here, chr(x) will return you the string type.

Answer (score 7):

### shortest way

```
for c in list(map(chr,range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1))):
    do_something(base_url+c)
```

---

iterate function

```
def plusplus(oldChar):
     return chr(ord(oldChar)+1)
plusplus('a') # output - b
```

---

Another option

```
url=www.website.com/term
my_char=ord('a') # convert char to ascii
while my_char<= ord('z'):
   my_char+=1 # iterate over abc
   my_url=url+chr(my_char)  # convert ascii to char
   do_something(my_url)
```

Based on @Brian answer.